# While do I get a compile error when I connect output reg of one module to input of another?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, system-verilog

```
module lab3(input [9:0] SW, input [3:0] KEY,
        output [6:0] HEX0, output [6:0] HEX1, output [6:0] HEX2,
        output [6:0] HEX3, output [6:0] HEX4, output [6:0] HEX5,
        output [9:0] LEDR);
wire clk = ~KEY[0]; // this is your clock
wire rst_n = KEY[3]; // this is your reset; your reset should be synchronous and active-low
wire [3:0] state_in;
reg [3:0] b;

assign state_in = state;

    //  moore component
    module moore(input [3:0] SW, 
         input clk, 
         input rst_n, 
         output reg [3:0] state);
    endmodule: moore

     // combinational component
     module combinational(input [3:0] SW, input [3:0] state_in,
                 output [6:0] HEX0, output [6:0] HEX1, output [6:0] HEX2,
                 output [6:0] HEX3, output [6:0] HEX4, output [6:0] HEX5);
     endmodule: combinational

 endmodule: lab3
```

My intention is to connect the output reg 'state' from the 'moore' module to the input of the 'combination' module (reg 'state' in this case is meant to act as a flip flop).

I know that a `reg` can drive a `wire` using an 'assign' statement, which is what I tried above. The file compiles when the placeholder `reg` 'b' is used to drive the wire, but when I try to connect it to the output `reg` 'state' from the 'moore' module, it doesn't compile. I'm struggling to understand why this is the case since I'm new to Verilog.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where *state* is defined in module *lab3*... so the statement `assign state_in = state;` has the effect of implicitly declaring a 1-bit wire called *state* inside module *lab3*. This is in no way related to the similarly named output port of module *moore*, because it's in a different lexical scope.

To connect ports from one instance of a module to another instance of a module, you have to create the instances at a higher level.

Inside the scope of module *lab3*, you need to create an instance of *moore* and an instance of *combinational*, and for best practice declare the connecting wires too (otherwise they default to a single 1-bit width). That's where you connect the input ports and output ports of the various instances together. Not inside the definition of module *moore* or module *combinational*.

If you're coming to Verilog from a computer programming language like C++ or Java, it's going to be very confusing, because you may be accustomed to reading the code as a series of steps to be performed by a computer. But in Verilog, it's not like that at all: it's all about defining a single piece of hardware, which exists in its complete and final form for the entire scope of the project. So while it's tempting to think of Verilog modules as if they were C++ class definitions, that's not really a good analogy. It only gets you as far as definition/instance, except that all of the instances must be created at compile time, and there's no dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st step is to move the `moore` and `combinational` module bodies out of the `lab3` module.

The 2nd step is to place an instance of the `moore` and `combinational` modules inside the `lab3` module.  Use unique instance names, like `i0` and `i1`.

The 3rd step is to make signal connections to the instances.  I use the connection-by-name style in this example:

```
module lab3(input [9:0] SW, input [3:0] KEY,
        output [6:0] HEX0, output [6:0] HEX1, output [6:0] HEX2,
        output [6:0] HEX3, output [6:0] HEX4, output [6:0] HEX5,
        output [9:0] LEDR);
wire clk = ~KEY[0]; // this is your clock
wire rst_n = KEY[3]; // this is your reset; your reset should be synchronous and active-low
wire [3:0] state_in;
reg [3:0] b;

moore         i0 (.state    (state_in), .SW(SW[3:0]), .clk(clk), .rst_n(rst_n));
combinational i1 (.state_in (state_in) /* connect other signals here */);

endmodule: lab3

module moore(input [3:0] SW, 
    input clk, 
    input rst_n, 
    output reg [3:0] state);
endmodule: moore

module combinational(input [3:0] SW, input [3:0] state_in,
    output [6:0] HEX0, output [6:0] HEX1, output [6:0] HEX2,
    output [6:0] HEX3, output [6:0] HEX4, output [6:0] HEX5);
endmodule: combinational
```

The above code compiles without any errors.  You need to complete the connections yourself for the `i1` instance.

Note that there is no need to use `assign` for the state; just connect the same signal (`state_in`) directly to both instances.

See also: [How to instantiate a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066850/verilog-how-to-instantiate-a-module)